# Can I limit the size of the popup window? Can't seem to manage to do it

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to write a small extension.

I have this in my `manifest.json`

```
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
```

and then the `popup.html` is just the default one that is provided in the google tutorial. I added this piece of css to restrict the popup's size, to make it stop growing (because I have an element that expands in it)

```
    html {
        max-width: 500px;
        max-height: 500px;
        overflow: scroll;
    }
```

As you can see in the immage, the extension however doesn't care about the restrictions I put, and goes well beyone those 500 x 500 px that I'd like it to stay in.

I also tried setting tha `max-width` and `max-height` on the body, and on the element that expands - same result.

Any ideas?

**[EDIT]**
My resolution was too small, so it just seemed that the html was going over the limits, when in fact it was not.

[image]

Comment: How are wee to answer the question given what you have provided?

Comment: The popup in your picture is 282x484 and doesn't exceed the restrictions. What's the problem?

Comment: @wOxxOm that was it actually. My resolution was waay to small. I was using a laptop that i'm not normally using - I just thought the screen must be  significantly larger than 500px, but I was wrong.

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith dunno how, but the info was enough for wOxxOm. Please be more polite.

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is change the `max-width` to `width` and `max-height` to `height` and you should have the desired result.

Comment: it turns out it actually worked. my resolution was waaay to small, and so i thought that the limit of 500px was broken, when in fact it wasn't

Comment: It worked but had to push different releases for browser extension and web app.